# Access database from one ipad to the other using the same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sqlite

Is this doable

I have one application say App XYZ in one ipad and the same app is installed in the other ipad, now i would like to access the sqlite database of the second ipad for few entries from the first one. So is it possible to do it and if yes then what are the ways to achieve it, please note that i would not like to use the web service or icloud.

One solution that i have thought of is using ports but is this possible?

**Update:** I want to support the OS version from 4.3 to latest 7.0.4

Comment: One Database are access on many phone but this database is a like server that locate globly, and it can be access using webservice

Comment: NO. .how can you access the database of the iPad outside of the application.. All Applications are sandboxed in iOS and AFAIK you cannot take out database or access it with ports (might be possible in jail broken phone)

Comment: Yes, it's possible as long as the app is running on _both_ iPads simultaneously and one app is designated as the server.

Comment: @neilco: Yes the app is running on both the ipads but they are not jail breaked is it still possible and how is it possible i do not want to use web services or ports for the same.

Comment: @user2538944 Yes, it's still possible but you cannot directly access the database on one device from another. You have to provide a communication service (either via Bluetooth or TCP/IP) that enables one iPad (the client) access the other (the server) and query its database.

Comment: @neilco : Ok thanks for the update will try this out and update this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Peer-to-Peer Connectivity to communicate between two devices and you can create private interface to exchange the data.
Have a look on the classes:

• MCBrowserViewController

• MCAdvertiserAssistant

• MCNearbyServiceBrowser

• MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser

• MCPeerID

• MCSession

It's very easy to use it.
If you have to support iOS < 7 as well have a look on Apple's GameKit framework.
They have some functionality you can use to exchange the data between phones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the above classes are available from ios 7 onwards i want the app to work from ios 4.3 to ios 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

completly without your own webservice its in my opinion only possible inside a local network, where you can assign fix ips for each ipad you want to communicate with. if you want to use it over the public internet, normaly all devices have dynamic ips and so the devices will not know how to reach the others.

if you know the ips of the devices and can establish a network connection, you can exchange the data easily.

Comment: ok so in the same network can the first ipad make a request like select * from tablename where DOJ = '15/07/1988' and what are the callback or notification methods that i need to use for the same?

Can i use NSOutput and NSInoutStream for the same

Comment: there are different ways to do that. one would be the mentioned peer-tp-peer connection. you would establish a connection and then provide your own protocoll to exchange data. so if you want to send sql-like statements, the other side must understand that, request the data from his table and send the result back. for the resonse i would use json formatted data strings.

Comment: another way is to run a webservice directly on the ipad with the database. so you could sent the request to that webserver. the prodedure on the server would be the nearly the same as with peer-to-peer. in my opinion with webservice would be easier because you have a well defined ip protocol and can easily sent requests and resonses.